# Unifying Transformations in Complex 3-Space

Tags: complex-analysis, rotations, complex-geometry, exterior-algebra, mobius-transformation

I am currently researching the vector space $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ and I was wondering if it is possible to generate a scheme of unifying the rigid transformations in $\mathbb{C}^{3}$. I know that in the extended complex plane one can perform Möbius transformations to produce rotations, translations, and reflections, but can this also be done in an elegant way for bivectors?

My question, then, is this: if $\textbf{e}_{x}$, $\textbf{e}_{y}$, and $\textbf{e}_{z}$ were the respective planes of $\mathbb{C}^{3}$, would it be possible to then perform transformations on the x, y, z planes together, independently, and in any arbitrary order using a unified algebraic scheme? A friend of mine mentioned exterior algebras for this, but I am unfamiliar with the process. Can one mix Möbius transformations and rotation matrices to perform this, and if so, can I be pointed in the right direction with examples in the literature?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "rigid transformations", but the natural things to study in the setting of complex analysis are biholomorphisms, and the automorphism group of $\mathbb{C}^3$ (the group of biholomorphic mappings $\mathbb{C}^3 \to \mathbb{C}^3$ is **huge**

Comment: A rigid transformation is just a rotation, reflection, or translation. 

Is there any literature on that that specific group of biholomorphic mappings? Also, do you know of a method to perform the specified transformations in the manner I described using Euler's formula over $\mathbb{C}^{3}$? I tried that out myself but found it too clunky and inelegant.

Comment: Very few Möbius transformations are rigid, and I don't really understand exactly what it is you want to do. Rigid transformations are just mappings on the form $f(x) = Ax + b$, where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix (with $\det A = 1$ if you want to exclude reflections), no matter the dimension.

Comment: "I don't really understand exactly what it is you want to do"

I'm just after a unified scheme to perform arbitrary transformations of arbitrary dimension up to 3 on $\mathbb{C}^{3}$. I supposed that Möbius transformations and rotation matrices might be one way, and exterior algebras might be another way.